# Python error with attributes and inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I have an error using Python, but I don't know how fix it. I have some clases, a class "App", "Controller" and "Console". Console inherits from Controller and Controller inherits from App.

class Console(Controller):
...

class Controller(App):
...

class App():
...

The class Controller has an attribute "commands", it is a list. The class Console has a function "write_command" that call a Controller's function.

This is the class "Console"

```
class Console(Controller):

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(Console, cls).__new__(cls)

def __init__(self):
    print('Init the console')

def __del__(self):
    print('Destructor console')

def write_command(self):
    command = input('Please write something: ')

    if self.exit_from_console(command):
        print('Bye')

    else:
        if self.is_valid_command(command):
            print(super().do_something(0, command))
        else:
            print('Que vergüenza, estoy algo confundido')
        self.write_command()

def is_valid_command(self, command):
    # Check if command is valid
    return super().validate_command(command)

@staticmethod
def exit_from_console(command):
    if command == 'exit':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This is the code of Controller's class:

```
class Controller(App):

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(Controller, cls).__new__(cls)

def __init__(self):

    # Temp Command list. Get it from DB
    self.commands = [('caminar', 'walk', 1),
                     ('correr', 'run', 2),
                     ('saltar', 'jump', 3),
                     ('saludar', 'hello', 4),
                     ('', '', 5),
                     ('', '', 6),
                     ('', '', 7)
                     ]

    self.users = ['0', 'System', 'Scenary']

    print('Init de controller')

def validate_command(self, command):
    # Search in local data base for command
    found = False
    the_commands = self.commands

    for i in the_commands:
        if i[0] == command.lower() or i[1] == command.lower():
            found = True
            break

    return found

def get_commands(self):
    pass

def do_something(self, user, command):
    for item in self.commands:
        if item[0] == command.lower or item[1] == command.lower:
            return super().play(user, item[2])

    return 'Nothing'

def get_commands(self):
    return self.commands
```

And the class App, has a function play()

The error is:

***AttributeError: 'Console' object has no attribute 'commands'***

That's true, but I'm not using this attribute from Console, But the Controller class, which does have it defined.

Thank you!

PD: I apologize if this is silly, but I am new to Python.

Comment: Can you include how you are instantiating the object and what function you are calling?

Comment: and a full stack trace would be nice as well

Comment: You didn't call `Controller.__init__` from `Console.__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the init function for the super class
you should call:

```
super(Console, self).__init__()
```